# Need help with determining the initial rate of change of pressure a person walking a certain direction experiences

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

The pressure in a certain region is given by $$P = x^2y - xe^z + ysin(2xz)$$.

Determine the pressure gradient at the point (1,2,0)

Determine the initial rate of change in the pressure experienced by a person setting off from this point in the direction of the vector $$2i  - 4j + k$$

I have done the first part I believe $$∇(x,y,z)$$, partially differentiating the pressure function in relation to each parameter. $$∇_x = 2xy - e^z +2yzcos(2xz)$$, $$∇_y = x^2 + sin(2xz)$$ and $$∇_z = -xze^z + 2xycos(2xz) $$ and finally substituting point (1,2,0) into each of these to get $$∇(x,y,z) = (3,1,0)$$

However, I have no idea how to do the second part of the question so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You’re being asked to compute a directional derivative. I suspect you’ve at least heard of those if you’re being given problems like this one.

Comment: The formula was shown but not how to apply it, so it is the first time I am attempting to calculate a directional derivative.

Comment: The formula involves a gradient and a unit vector, no? You’ve computed the gradient, so now you need a unit vector. Any ideas on how you might get one of those?

Comment: By the way, your $P_z$ is incorrect.

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing it out, tiredness is getting the better of me. Also thank you, following from what you suggested, I turned the given direction into an unit vector, then gradient I calculated dotted with the unit vector and that should be it if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact the inner product of gradient vector and unit vector along the given direction i.e.$$\text{Partial variation}=\nabla f.\vec{u}=(3,1,0)\cdot(2,-4,1)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{21}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{21}}$$